# Google Drive SDK in iOS

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I read tutorial google drive api for iOS

1. In Xcode, create a new workspace to contain the sample app and the Drive SDK which you'll add later on.
2. Create a new project for the app using the Single View Application template. Fill in the product, organization, and company identifier.
3. Add the client library by dragging GTL.xcodeproj into the workspace
   Update the application project's Build Phases "Link Binary with Libraries" list to include:
   libGTLTouchStaticLib.a from the GTL project. This is the client library.
4. Security.framework and SystemConfiguration.framework are required dependencies from the client library and also must be included.
5. MobileCoreServices.framework which contains code useful for accessing the camera.
6. Add -ObjC -all_load to the Other Linker Flags setting in the application project's Build Settings.
7. Also in the application project's Build Settings, add the client library headers to the application project by adding the Source directory of the GTL project to the User headers search path section with the recursive option.
8. Drag GTMOAuth2ViewTouch.xib from client library's Source/OAuth2/Touch folder into the app's Supporting Files folder.
9. Add the Google Drive service by adding GTLDrive.h and GTLDrive_Sources.m from the Source/Services/Drive/Generated folder directly to the application project.

But when i implementation step above, error occurs:`GTLDriveConstants.m file not found`, how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to include Source directory in "User Search Header Path" (Recursively) By default it is non-recursive. (Step 7 above)

Comment: @NhuNguyen i do not understand what u mean by adding source. I am getting the same error

Comment: @NhuNguyen i would like if u can let me know how to fix this

Comment: @MuhammadUmar I am facing same issue.Does adding User Search Header Path solve the problem?

Comment: @iosdeveloper Hell no, i just copied Entire folder in my code :)

Comment: @MuhammadUmar Does copying entire folder works for you? Please guide me.If it works for you i could try that.